# Bluedroid hangs up for >45 ms during channel switch

Tags: android, android-source, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have an application that needs to transmit bursts of data to android device.

A sequence of packets during this burst is attached. We observe that during channel change, stack goes too busy and does not transmit anything for ~45-48 ms.

[image: capture during burst]

This leads to data loss on transmitting device. We cannot hold that amount of data on transmitter to cope with delay in bluedroid.

Are there any suggested changes in AOSP / bluedroid that can improve this situation? Any suggestions on where to start looking?

Target device is Nexus 7 2013 (flo) with AOSP 5.1.1_r14

Comment: I couldn't add bluedroid tag because anyone with less than 1500 reputation shouldn't be asking questions about it. Is there any brave and reputed soul out there who could attach bluedroid tag to this question for me please. Thanks...

Comment: On further investigations, it seems like default conn-interval of 48.75 ms is in effect and master & slave didn't negotiate correctly for smaller conn-interval.
Even so, why would master wait for remainder ~46ms before sending its empty packet? Is there an upper limit on packets that could be transmitted during one conn-interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MD column is "More Data" it tells if transmitter has more data to send. In this case, Slave sets MD=0 on 4th transmitted packet on every CI and so master goes away. Master checks back in next CI with empty packet.

In my application, somehow this gap is 46 ms due to issue in negotiating ConnInterval, so master defaults to 48.75 ms CI. And so it sleeps for ~46ms

My data loss is happening due to issue mentioned by @Gaurav, but on Slave, i.e. Slave LL is dropping packets fed to it while it already has 4 packets. [This is a guess] I'll confirm and update.

---

### Update

Looks like CONNECT_IND contained transmitWindowSize of 2.5ms in the captured log, transmission of 4 packets will take 2.3+ms, and 5th packet wont fit in 2.5 ms.  transmitWindowSize might be the real reason why no more than 4 packets are transmitted per CI, still doesn't explain MD=0 in 4th packet though.

Comment: transmitWindowSize has nothing to do with the length of a connection event. It rather defines some information about the first connection event.

Comment: Im facing similar problem on Android and ble peripheral. I connect to a BLE peripheral and exchange dozens of packets (say 300) in approximately 20-30 seconds and then communication become very slow, starting taking 1.5sec, to write a characteristic and getting back its response. This amount of time is not acceptable for my application.

If I disconnect and reconnect after every few hundred packets and resume process from there than it never slows down or stop working. Is this issue is related to limit of packets per connection or time duration for connection. Please help

Comment: @Bilal Its dfficult to speculate reason for your issue without more inside info. Do you ave a sniffer? Perhaps you should collect info on your issue, and post it as a question.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably hardware specific behavior. Perhaps the hardware buffer is limited to 4 packets, and driver delivers/fetches packets only during interrupt on CI elapse.