# BLE: Max number of packets in Connection interval

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Is there a limit on maximum number of packets (LE_DATA) that could be send by either slave or master during one connection interval?

If this limit exists, are there any specific conditions for this limit (e.g. only x number of ATT data packets)?

Are master/slave required or allowed to impose such a limit by specification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could find the following in Bluetooth Spec v4.2:

> **4.5.6 Closing Connection Events**
>
> The MD bit of the Header of the Data Channel PDU is used to indicate
>   that the device has more data to send. If neither device has set the
>   MD bit in their packets, the packet from the slave closes the
>   connection event. If either or both of the devices have set the MD
>   bit, the master may continue the connection event by sending another
>   packet, and the slave should listen after sending its packet. If a
>   packet is not received from the slave by the master, the master will
>   close the connection event. If a packet is not received from the
>   master by the slave, the slave will close the connection event.
>
> Two consecutive packets received with an invalid CRC match within a
>   connection event shall close the event.

This means both slave and masters have self-imposed limit on number of packets they want to transmit during a CI. When either party doesn't wish to send more data, they just set this bit to 0 and other one understands. This should usually be driven by number of pending packets on either side.

Since I was looking for logical limits due to spec or protocol, this probably answers my question.

Physical limits to number packets per CI would be governed by data rate, and as @morynicz mentioned, on MTU etc.

Comment: This is old, but just to be clear I don't think this really answered your question, but rather explained the mechanism by which an answer to your question would be implemented.  The takeaway from the quoted section is that the master has final discretion on whether the connection event will continue for a given connection interval (assuming at least one of the master and slave packets had MD bit set).  However, the real question is if there is a knob provided from the link layer that will affect whether the MD bit gets set.

Answer (score 3):

*(I hope I'm not reviving a dead post. But I think the section 4.5.1 is better suited to answer this than 4.5.6.)*

The spec doesn't define a limit of packets. It just states the following:

> **4.5.1 Connection Events - BLUETOOTH SPECIFICATION Version 4.2 [Vol 6, Part B]**
>
> (...)
>
> The start of a connection event is called an anchor point. At the anchor point, a master shall start to transmit a Data Channel PDU to the slave. The start of connection events are spaced regularly with an interval of connInterval and shall not overlap. **The master shall ensure that a connection event closes at least T_IFS before the anchor point of the next connection event.** The slave listens for the packet sent by its master at the anchor point.

*T_IFS* is the "Inter Frame Space" time and shall be 150 μs. Simply put it's the job of the master to solve this problem. As far as I know iOS limits the packet number to 4 per connection event for instance. Android may have other hard coded limits depending on the OS version.

Comment: It's actually the Bluetooth Controller (the dedicated chip in the phone) that decides this. First, in order to be able to send many packets during one connection interval there must be no other connections or WiFi things that want to use the radio in the meantime. Second, in the HCI protocol the host can hint about the desired length of the connection event. Android just sets this to 0 which means it lets the controller decide this. Not sure what iOS sets. Then it completely depends on how smart the controller is. Some controllers simply limit it to 4 packets when given 0 as CE_len.

Comment: @Emil Thx for the addition! What i wonder in this conext is: Does the controller realy calculate if the time at the end of an connection event fits another T_IFS or do they pick the values so the number of max packets won't collide even with max packet length?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I was looking for limits imposed by specification, not implementations. Per spec, transmissions in one CI stop when both sides reset their MD bit, so spec doesn't put a limit on number of packets either device could transmit on one CI, except through time taken per pkt tx. Spec does not disallow self imposing stricter limit, which most BLE controllers actually impose, as I found out later.

Comment: @GPS Either I don't get your point or your whole comment is a recap of my answer... First sentence is "The spec doesn't define a limit of packets" - that is the answer, there are none. At least no direct ones.

Comment: We both agree that there is no direct limit imposed by spec. I guess we could close discussion there.

Answer (score 1):

There is max data rate that can be achieved both on BT and BLE. You can tweak this data rate by changing MTU (maximum transmission unit - packet size) up to max MTU both ends of transmission can handle. But AFAIK there is no straight constraint on number of packets, besides physical ones imposed by the data rate.

You can find more in the [spec](https://www.bluetooth.org/DocMan/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=286439)

Comment: I specifically wanted to know of limits on number of packets per CI. I observe that my master device never sends more than 4 packets per CI. [[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36542079/bluedroid-hangs-up-for-45-ms-during-channel-switch)] Could this be due to some negotiation (e.g. only allowed to transmit for a limited time) or due to limited number of buffers on hw, or bad coding in drivers etc.

Comment: Im facing similar problem on Android and ble peripheral. I connect to a BLE peripheral and exchange dozens of packets (say 300) in approximately 20-30 seconds and then communication become very slow, starting taking 1.5sec, to write a characteristic and getting back its response. This amount of time is not acceptable for my application.

If I disconnect and reconnect after every few hundred packets and resume process from there than it never slows down or stop working. Is this issue is related to limit of packets per connection or time duration for connection. Please help

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, the limit is: min{max master event length, max slave event length, connection interval}.

To clarify, both the master and slave devices (specifically, the BLE stack thereof) typically have event length or "GAP event length" times.  This time limit may be used to allow a central and/or advertiser and/or broadcaster to schedule the "phase offset" of more than one BLE radio activity, and/or limit the CPU usage of the BLE stack for application processing needs.  E.g. a Nordic SoftDevice stack may have a default event length of 3.75ms that is indefinitely extendable (up to the connection interval) based on other demands on the SoftDevice's scheduler.  In Android and iOS BLE implementations, this value may be opaque or not specified (e.g. Android may set this value to "0", which leaves the decision up to the controller implementation associated with the BLE chip of that device).

Note also that either the master or the slave may effectively "drop out" of a connection event earlier than these times if their TX/RX buffers are filled (e.g. Nordic SoftDevice stack may have a buffer size of 6 packets/frames).  This may be implemented by not setting the MD bit (if TX buffer is exhausted) and/or "nacking" with the NESN bit (if RX buffer is full).  However, while the master device can actually "drop out" by ending the connection event (not sending any more packets), the slave device must listen for master packets as long as at least one of master and slave have the MD bit set and the master continues to transmit packets (e.g. the slave could keep telling the master that it has no more data and also keep NACKing master packets because it has no more buffer space for the current connection event, but the master may keep trying to send for as long as it wants during the connection interval; not sure how/if the controller stack implements any "smarts" regarding this).

If there are no limits from either device in terms of stack-specified event length or buffer size, then presumably packets could be transmitted back and forth the entire connection interval (assuming at least one side had data to send and therefore set the MD bit).  Just note for throughput calculation purposes that there is a T_IFS spacing (currently specified at 150us) between each packet and before the end of the connection interval.

Comment: This is a very good answer! The only thing I'm a bit sceptical to which I think is wrong is the part about "dropping out of a connection event earlier". For example, "NACKing" packets definitely does not result in an early termination. Also if the RX data buffer is full doesn't mean you should stop listen because Link Layer packets can still be received since they are not put in the same RX buffer.

Comment: @Emil Thanks.  Actually, yeah the NACKing itself does not stop the connection event (I will update the answer), but it does stop the NACKer from receiving any more data as long as it NACKs (since the peer will just keep resending until it gets an ACK via NESN).  I do believe there is a link layer buffer limit on many implementations which may effectively ceiling the throughput per connection event (and therefore per connection interval).

Comment: @Emil As far as an early termination, it is totally up to the master device.  So the slave must listen even if it's full, but the master may terminate the connection event even if both sides still have data to send and capacity to receive.