# BLE: transmitWindowSize: can it be controlled?

Tags: android, android-source, bluetooth-lowenergy

In Connect indication, Master sends to Slave some parameters, of which, I am interested in controlling transmitWindowSize and transmitWindowOffset

Is there any way I could control these parameters in Bluedroid/AOSP 5.x?

Example connect indication:
[image: Connect indication]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TransmitWindowSize and TransmitWindowOffset define a time frame for the first connection event of a connection.  They allow Master phy to schedule the connection event in a time slot where it will not conflict with other connections.  There is nothing you can - and should - do about it from an application standpoint.

If you are trying to get more packets transmitted during one Connection Event, Window is not what you are looking for.  In the spec, a connection event can last for at most (ConnectionInterval - 150µs) (See 6.B.4.5.1).

Bad thing is most (if not all) BLE radio chips found in USB dongles, computers and phones enforce a limitation ways lower, usually 8-10 packets per connection event (4-5 each way).  This is usually a chip's firmware limitation (memory constraints, or other).

Comment: Motivation for this came from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36542079/bluedroid-hangs-up-for-45-ms-during-channel-switch).
I observed that no more than 4 data pkts were xmitted from slave to master, and this took enough time so that next packet wont fit in my 2.5 ms transmit window. 
Is it not true that within any connection interval, master and slave will engage in communication with each other only for transmitWindow duration?
Also, is there any way to control TransmitWindow from hci?
Is there any other method to get more packets through within a CI?
Thanks..

Comment: The Connection Event Transmit Window is the time slot for transmitting first packet of a connection event. It can be:

* dependant on Transmit Window Size and Transmit Window Offset upon connection initialization (first packet) or after a Connection Parameters Update;
* a +/- 16µs window, _connectionInterval_ after first packet of previous connection event.

Connection event may span after the end of the Window, for (_ConnectionInterval_ - 150µs)

Comment: OK. Understood. So 4 pkt limitation in reference question was not due to transmitWindowSize, but some other reason, perhaps limited buffer count or similar. Thanks.

Comment: If you are in control of the HCI, you can increase Maximum_CE_Length to get larger connection events.

Comment: @Emil Thanks. I don't control Link Layer. I primarily struggle to implement our proprietary protocols in applications.